# Why operator< of c++ map do not work with <=

Tags: c++, stl

I have this following program for map with custom keys:

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    MyClass(int i): val(i) {}

    bool operator< (const MyClass& that) const { return val <= that.val; }

private:
    int val;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass c1(1);
    MyClass c2(2);
    MyClass c3(3);

    map<MyClass, int> table;

    table[c1] = 12;
    table[c2] = 22;
    table[c3] = 33;

    cout << "Mapped values are: " << table.lower_bound(c1)->second << " " << table[c2] << " " << table[c3] << endl;

}
```

The output comes as:

```
Mapped values are: 22 0 0
```

But if I compare using < or > in the operator< instead of <= then everything works fine. And the output comes as:

```
Mapped values are: 12 22 33
```

Can someone explain why <= does not work at all, but < and even > works?

Comment: it need strict less

Comment: Keys have to be unique in a map.

Comment: strict weak ordering https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering Fairly obviously `bool operator< (const MyClass& that) const { return val <= that.val; }` is not doing what it says it is doing.

Comment: If you implement `operator+` to perform division, would you ask why it's not working?

Comment: @Charles: You could implement a map that uses `<=` as its comparison and still has unique keys. It just turns out that `std::map` is not implemented that way.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley that's pretty much what i meant. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comparison function used by `std::map` must implement a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).  That means it must implement the following rules given objects `x`, `y`, and `z`:

- `op(x, x)` must always be false
- if `op(x, y)` is true then `op(y, x)` must be false
- if `op(x, y) && op(y, z)` is true then `op(x, z)` must also be true
- if `!op(x, y) && !op(y, x)` is true then `!op(x, z) && !op(z, x)` must also be true

The `<=` operator does not satisfy these conditions because, given `x = y = 1`, `x <= x` is not false and both `x <= y` and `y <= x` are true.

`std::map` uses these rules to implement its comparisons.  For example, it could implement an equality check as `!(op(x, y) || op(y, x))`.  Given `x = 4`, `y = 4`, and `op = operator<=` this becomes `!(4 <= 4 || 4 <= 4)`, so `4` does not compare equal to `4` because the first rule above was broken.

Answer (score 1):

On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) we find this quote.

> Everywhere the standard library uses the Compare concept, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, two objects a and b are considered equivalent (not unique) if neither compares less than the other: !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a).

This means that with you current compare

```
bool operator< (const MyClass& that) const { return val <= that.val; }
```

if you have two `MyClass` with `val` 5 and 5, `5 <= 5` will return true, and they will not be considered equivalent.